# How to call a jquery function based on button class name

Tags: php, jquery, class, button

I have a few button created in PHP,  when I try calling a jQuery function based on the button class name. The function on click doesn't seem to work.

PHP

```
$style = " margin: 0px; background-color: transparent; border: none;";
    $functionname= "selectedpic(this.id)";
    $styleimage = "HEIGHT= 120  WIDTH= 120  BORDER= 0";
    $eventimage1= "zoomin(this)";
    $eventimage2= "zoomout(this)";
    $btnclass="btnclass";

echo "<button name='" . $btn. "'
            margin ='".$style."'
            onClick='".$functionname."'
            class='".$btnclass."'
            >";
```

jquery

```
$(".btnclass").click(function () {
var clickedButtonName = this.name;
   alert ("hi");
 });
```

Comment: you maybe have a conflict between onClick and your jquery function, try without onclick

Comment: Most probably function may bind click event to elements which have "btnClass" before you creating targeted buttons. Or simply bind event before dom is ready.

Comment: What is error console ?

Comment: And now paste What You see in Browser for <button> .So we will come to know error

Comment: it doesnt work when i remove the conflict. I believe there is a problem with binding.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok make sure the javascript is inside `<script></script>` tags

and try wrapping your jQuery code in `$(document).ready();` ie.

```
 $(function(){
    $(".btnclass").click(function () {
      var clickedButtonName = this.name;
      alert ("hi");
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<button name='" . $btn. "'
            margin ='".$style."'
            onClick='".$functionname."'
            class='staticClass ".$btnclass."'
            >";


    $('.staticClass').on('click', function(){
        var clickedButtonName = this.name;
        alert('hi');
    })
```

Create a class for binding events, this will not change according to PHP parameter. The other class is dynamic and change based on PHP parameter this can be used for calculation.

Comment: I have tried this and working for me :). Have you tried this using "ON"?

Answer (score 0):

Use to get name

```
$(this).attr("name");
```

Instead of `this.name;`.

And mostly use "on" delegate/event , as it supports event(like click) for Dynamic elements also.